# Drools : Setting a flag from within the drl file

Tags: java, drools

I am testing for some conditions within a Drools drl file, and if any of these conditions is true, I want to set a flag in the calling program.

I tried doing this in the following manner :

--- drl file ----

```
//created on: 28 Aug, 2013
package flowManagers

import flowHelper.OrderRelatedQueriesFlowHelper;
import entity.Order;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

global Logger logger;
global Boolean isValid;

rule "isValid"
no-loop
salience -1
activation-group "AC1" 

when
        $o : Order( OrderRelatedQueriesFlowHelper.isValid($o))
then 
        isValid=Boolean.TRUE;
        logger.info("Valid order..." );
end
```

--- calling program bit ----

```
    Boolean isValid=Boolean.FALSE;
    String[] noHappyOrderFileList={"NoHappyOrder.drl"};
    StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = createKnowledgeSession( noHappyOrderFileList );
    ksession.setGlobal("logger", logger);
    ksession.setGlobal( "isValid", isValid);
    for( Order fo : coll )
    {           
        ksession.insert(fo);
    }
    ksession.fireAllRules();

    logger.info("Valid?? : " + isValid );
```

But even when the logger prints "Valid order..." within the drl file, the calling program still prints isValid as false.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drools works with "Facts" not objects. A fact is an object but every object is not a fact. Please think about what Boolean.TRUE represents.

Then think about the following code:

```
when
  $orderstatus : OrderStatus(...)
then
  modify ($orderstatus) {
     valid = Boolean.TRUE
  }
```

Validity of an OrderStatus fact can only mean one thing, but Boolean.TRUE have a too broad meaning to be used as a fact.

Comment: Hi alikox, what you have said would definitely work, but my use case is slightly different... I have a list of orders that I am passing through a series of rules. If ANY of the rules are satisfied for ANY of the orders, all the orders are also automatically valid. ( Valid for a discount ). This is why I am setting the valid flag as a global value. If I followed your approach, I would have to go through all the orders one by one once the rules have been fired to check if any of them have the valid flag set. I was just wondering if a simpler solution is possible ? Thanks.

Comment: Just add a filed isValid to OrderStatus fact as suggested by @alikox. You can for example query the results afterwards. If you add a condition to your rules where you check whether the order was set valid already previously, you'll avoid setting the value over and over again in each valid order/rule. You can also have a low-salience rule where you collect all OrderStatus facts to a global list for accessing from outside the rules.

Comment: @arya You do not have to declare a status fact for each of your orders. You can rename your fact as GlobalOrderStatus and the attribute as anyOrderValid if you like. On the other hand, if you do use an OrderStatus fact for each of your orders, you can use accumulate function to find out the number of facts that have valid flags. Regards.

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you :) Also @J Andy : The low salience rule idea is also a really cool one ! Thanks :)